# two fields, one name jsonproperty

Tags: java, jackson, java-8

I have an interface A which has two methods with different jsonproperty (ref: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty) names

```
public interface  A {
  @JsonProperty("field_1")
    String getField1();

    @JsonProperty("field_2")
    String getField2();
}
```

I need to create two more interfaces class B and C which will inherit from A.

While B wants to include field_1 and discard field_2, C wants field_2 and discard field_1. Also, both want to give the same name to their preferred fields, lets say, "field_3".

Comment: so your question is..?

Comment: @comiventor check out Jackson JsonViews. Its for context-based serialization. Maybe that can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@JsonIgnore` to discard fields and `B` and `C` can override `@JsonProperty` of `A` as shown below.

```
    public interface A {

    @JsonProperty("field_1")
    String getField1();

    @JsonProperty("field_2")
    String getField2();
}

public class B implements A {

    @Override
    @JsonProperty("field_B")
    public String getField1() {
        return "field1";
    }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getField2() {
        return "field2";
    }

}

public class C implements A {

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getField1() {
        return "field1";
    }

    @Override
    @JsonProperty("field_C")
    public String getField2() {
        return "field2";
    }

}
```

Comment: JsonIgnore will only mean the method will not be part of serialization but the method e.g. getField1 in class C will still be available for explicit calling, right? Also, in my case, there will be no field_C or field_B. field_1 will be used as the name for both classes.